# MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 error

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
at \_handleConnectionErrors (/home/mandil/code/mallamandilcoding/mongodb/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:755:11)
at NativeConnection.openUri (/home/mandil/code/mallamandilcoding/mongodb/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:730:11) {
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'Unknown',
servers: Map(1) { '127.0.0.1:27017' =\> \[ServerDescription\] },
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: null,
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined
```

i tried every possbile way from the internet but still not able to connect it.

1. i made the data/db folder in c:
2. i restarted my mongod from the services
3. reinstalled mongo & mongoose again
4. mongoDb compass is connecting fine.

Comment: Is the MongoDB running?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes its running and confirmed it in the services tab